# PHP preg_replace: remove style=".." from img tags

Tags: php, regex, image, coding-style, preg-replace

I'm trying to find an expression for preg_replace, that deletes all inline css styles for images.
For example, I have this text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <img style="float:left; margin:0 0 10px 10px;" src="image.jpg" /> Proin vestibulum libero id nisl dignissim eu sodales.
```

And I need to make it look like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <img src="image.jpg" /> Proin vestibulum libero id nisl dignissim eu sodales.
```

I have tried dozens of expressions like

```
preg_replace("%<img(.*?)style(.*?)=(.*?)(\'|\")(.+?)(\'|\")(.*?)>%i", "<img\$1\$7>", $article->text)
```

but nothing worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use an HTML/XML parsing library. Attempting to parse HTML with regular expressions is a mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/(\<img[^>]+)(style\=\"[^\"]+\")([^>]+)(>)/', '${1}${3}${4}', $article->text)
```

this could help

Comment: I tried the expression you suggested but it seems to remove the whole image

Comment: I had to wrap the expression in quotes in order to make it work. The correct form of the statement is: preg_replace('/(\<img[^>]+)(style\=\"[^\"]+\")([^>]+)(>)/', '${1}${3}${4}', $text);

Comment: n.p. it worked fine after that correction anyway:) Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

As was commented you should use a dom parser, PHP has one built in (two in some cases) called DOMDocument. Here is how you could use it for your purpose.

```
$x = new DOMDocument();
    $x->loadHTMLFile("/path/to/html/file/or/file/outputtinghtml.html");
    foreach($x->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img)
    {
    $img->removeAttribute('style');
    }
$x->saveHTMLFile("/file/used/in/loadHTMLFile/function.html");
```

Comment: I tried to understand the solution you suggested. I'm not aware of the DOMDocument and I'm not a php expert:) There's a path to html file mentioned in yor code. My website is dynamically creating pages (I'm using joomla) and there's no such thing as path to a specific html file. Sorry if my question is dummy.

Comment: Well, you would send whatever string you are sending into preg_replace into the DOMDocument object using $x->loadHTML($htmlstring); everything else in the example would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is too permissive. Since `.` could match anything, `style(.*?)=(.*?)` will go on trying to match until it hits something with a = sign in it, including all sorts of stuff you don't want. You also aren't using the `g` or `m` flags, which I'm pretty sure you want to use.

Try something like this:

```
preg_replace("/<img\s([^>]*)style\s*=\s*('|\").*?\2([^>]*)>/igm", "<img $1 $3>", $article->text)
```

Note the `('|")...\2`, which allows code like `style="foo 'bar'"`. This is quite possible in `style` tags.

Comment: this might be a silly question but how I can I use the pattern you suggested without causing syntax errors? Should the expression be wrapped in "" or ''?

Comment: @ktsixit - I'm sorry, my fault. I haven't used PHP in a long time, so I didn't wrap it properly. Not sure what I was thinking there. I've edited; try it now. BTW, note that I've also escaped the `"` in `('|\")`.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
preg_replace('/<img style="[^"]*"/', '<img ', $article->text);
```

Comment: What happens if there is something between 'img' and 'style'?

Comment: @afuzzyllama Very good point! Bit of an oversight on my part!