# PHP preg_replace: remove style=“..” from all tags except img

Tags: php, regex, image, preg-replace, pcre

It is the reverse of : [PHP preg_replace: remove style=".." from img tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875518/php-preg-replace-remove-style-from-img-tags)

Im trying to find an expression for preg_replace, that deletes all inline css styles except for images. For example, I have this text:

```
<img attribut="value" style="myCustom" attribut='value' style='myCustom' /> <input attribut="value" style="myCustom" attribut='value' style='myCustom'> <span attribut="value" style="myCustom" attribut='value' style='myCustom'> style= </span>
```

And I need to make it look like:

```
<img attribut="value" style="myCustom" attribut='value' style='myCustom' /> <input attribut="value" "myCustom" attribut='value' 'myCustom'> <span attribut="value" "myCustom" attribut='value' 'myCustom'> style= </span>
```

or like this:

```
<img attribut="value" style="myCustom" attribut='value' style='myCustom' /> <input attribut="value" attribut='value'> <span attribut="value" attribut='value'> style= </span>
```

It might looks like this

```
preg_replace('/(\<img[^>]+)(style\=\"[^\"]+\")([^>]+)(>)/', '${1}${3}${4}', $article->text)
```

Comment: Using regexes for this is IMHO a very bad choice. Use PHP's DOM functionality instead.

Comment: Someone told me the same but Im not sure about the foreach

a reverse of http://stackoverflow.com/a/6875680/1075716

Comment: I'll go ahead and leave this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/350278. (TL;DR: Don't use regex to parse HTML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) issue can be answered with a simple negative assertion:

```
preg_replace('/(<(?!img)\w+[^>]+)(style="[^"]+")([^>]*)(>)/', '${1}${3}${4}', $article->text)
```

And a simpler approach might be using [querypath](/questions/tagged/querypath) (rather than fiddly DOMDocument):

```
FORACH htmlqp($html)->find("*")->not("img") EACH $el->removeAttr("style");
```

Comment: I have not enought reputation for vote Up, but this work. 
Note: it could maybe help other people if add checks for ' too (for the regex).
Thanks you very much

Comment: Add an alternative to conver both cases `(style="[^"]+"|style='[^']+')` (with backslashes on each single quote for string escaping!) then.

Answer (score 0):

This does as you've asked

```
$string = '<img attribut="value" style="myCustom" attribut=\'value\' style=\'myCustom\' /> <input attribut="value" style="myCustom" attribut=\'value\' style=\'myCustom\'> <span attribut="value" style="myCustom" attribut=\'value\' style=\'myCustom\'> style= </span>';

preg_match_all('/\<img.+?\/>/', $string, $images);

foreach ($images[0] as $i => $image) {    
    $string = str_replace($image,'--image'.$i.'--', $string);
}

$string = preg_replace(array('/style=[\'\"].+?[\'\"]/','/style=/'), '', $string);

foreach ($images[0] as $i => $image) {
    $string = str_replace('--image'.$i.'--',$image, $string);
}
```

**OUTPUTS**

```
<img attribut="value" style="myCustom" attribut='value' style='myCustom' /> <input attribut="value"  attribut='value' > <span attribut="value"  attribut='value' >  </span>
```

Comment: I tested your code but I did have this output: <img attribut="value" style=""> <input attribut="value"> <span attribut="value">  </span>

Comment: I just ran it again and got the expected output, glad you found a solution

<img attribut="value" style="myCustom" attribut='value' style='myCustom' /> <input attribut="value"  attribut='value' > <span attribut="value"  attribut='value' >  </span>

Answer (score -1):

A very simple regular expression to get rid of them, without going too much into it would be

```
preg_replace( '/style="(.*)"/', 'REPLACEMENT' )
```

Very simple, effective enough though

Comment: i was using a str_replace("style=", " ",  $html); but now images are not anymore floating or having the custom size

Comment: This would not help a bit with the question at hand.